# drf_yasg swagger_auto_schema move from views

Tags: django, swagger, drf-yasg

In my project's views classes I use `swagger_auto_schema` decorator to customize swagger possible responses. My question is this: "Is this a way to move all these decorators from my class based views to other place like module or python file?". I'm asking this question because swagger_auto_schema decorators sometimes take up most of the code of my views, and it's getting hard to read them.

example:

```py
class ArticleListCreateAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == "GET":
            return ArticleResponseSerializer
        return super().get_serializer_class()
    
    @swagger_auto_schema(
        responses={
            status.HTTP_201_CREATED: openapi.Response(
                description="Successful article create",
                schema=ArticleResponseSerializer,
            ),
            status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST: openapi.Response(
                description="Data serialization failed. Incorrect data.",
                schema=DetailResponseSerializer
            ),
            status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT: openapi.Response(
                description="Media-file is already bouned to some other model",
                schema=DetailResponseSerializer
            )
        }
    )
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

Maybe I should stop using swagger_auto_schema and replace it by some other structures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to separate responses parts, responses and swagger_auto_schema to 3 deffirent places. In my project root I've create `utils` folder, in which I store files in the following way:

```
utils
├── __init__.py
├── ...
└── swagger
   ├── __init__.py
   ├── generators.py            <---- http/https schema for swagger
   ├── response_templates.py    <---- templates of swagger_auto_schema response parts
   └── serializers.py           <---- some general response serializers
```

In `response_templates.py` there is following code:

```py
from drf_yasg import openapi
from rest_framework import status

from .serializers import DetailResponseSerializer, TaskRequestSerializer


FILE_SUCCESS_200 = {
    status.HTTP_200_OK: openapi.Response(
        description="Correct file get",
        schema=openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_FILE),
    ),
}

TASK_CREATED_201 = {
    status.HTTP_201_CREATED: openapi.Response(
        description="Successfully task created",
        schema=TaskRequestSerializer,
    ),
}

... # and other
```

So, I can use these response parts in my `swagger_auto_schema` decorator. The next step was to create `responses` folders in all applications, those needs custom responses in swagger. tree of responses folder:

```
responses
├── __init__.py
├── image.py
└── and_other_models_name_files.py
```

In `image.py` there is following code:

```py
from utils.swagger.response_templates import (
    TASK_CREATED_201, FILE_SUCCESS_200, CREATED_201, SERIALIZE_400, NOT_FOUND_404,
    LARGE_ENTITY_413, INVALID_FILE_FORMAT_415, SERVER_STORAGE_500
)


image_list_responses = {
    **TASK_CREATED_201,
    **SERIALIZE_400,
    **LARGE_ENTITY_413,
    **INVALID_FILE_FORMAT_415,
}

image_detail_responses = {
    **FILE_SUCCESS_200,
    **NOT_FOUND_404,
    **SERVER_STORAGE_500
}
```

So, as a result of above restructure, I can use above responses in `swagger_auto_schema` decorator. Example:

```py
from media_app.responses import image_detail_responses


class DetailDownloadAPIView(RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    @swagger_auto_schema(responses=image_detail_responses)
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

...
```